# Is it possible to change the default Device shown in the Preview view in InterfaceBuilder?

Tags: interface-builder, xcode7

As we all know, when you enter Preview in the assistant editor on a xib document, you are greeted with the "iPhone 4-inch" device. It is not possible to remove devices from the view once added. Has anyone researched a way to change the default device that appears? I can't imagine anyone designing with the 4-inch iPhone in mind. I really want to see 4.7-inch every time I use Preview. Further, suppose I was developing an iPad-only app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete a device by selecting it and click 'Delete' button from your keyboard (even first one created for 4 inch screen can be deleted). These changes are kept even after restarting Xcode.

Answer to your question is NO. There is no way to change this. A workaround would be to add the desired device, 4.7 inch in your case and delete default one. Next time when you'll preview your view you'll see the 4.7 inch device.

Comment: Thanks for this tip on this cryptic feature of Xcode! I did not realize that the device was selectable.